# Monodroid Timer Schedule

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need to run this sequence. I bring some error beginning from row 3. From how I see Xamarin don't have a definition for keyword "schedule" in System.Timers.Time and I tried to replace with something else. Now I'm thinking maybe I forget any namespace but I don't think so...

```
    private void updateDisplay() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {                //row where start the errors
            public void run() {
                //TextView.Text = count.ToString();
            }
        },0,1000);
    }
```

I tried by few times but I failed each time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What help do you need? What did you try? Why/How did you fail?

Comment: @azurefrog I need to run this sequence. I bring some error beginning from row 3. From how I see Xamarin don't have a definition for keyword "schedule" in System.Timers.Time and I tried to replace with something else. Now I'm thinking maybe I forget any namespace but I don't think so...

Comment: @azurefrog I don't understand what you exactly try to mean but I think is ready.

Comment: @azurefrog http://snag.gy/UYSnG.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is C#. You can't code Java in a C# environment. Meaning, you can't do anonymous classes like in Java. What you are trying to do there is to translate something that is Java to C#.

You are right. `System.Timers.Timer` does not have a method called `schedule`, why do you think it would have that? If you look at the [`System.Timers.Timer` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), then you will discover that it relies on an `Elapsed` `Event` instead. So your code needs to look more like:

```
var timer = new Timer();
timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
    // do stuff here
};
timer.Interval = 1000; //time in milliseconds to trigger Elapsed
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Conclusion:
In C# write C# not Java. In C# use C# types not Java types. Read the docs.